# Precalculus please help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that all the roots of $z^4 + z^2 + 1 = 0$ are $n$th roots of unity?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: $n=6$....................

Comment: Try to find a hidden second order equation.

Comment: Hint:  what's $(z^2-1)( z^4+z^2+1)$?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting query re pre-calculus tag combined with a complex analysis problem.

Hint:

The $n$-th roots of unity are the roots of

$$0 = (z^n - 1) = (z - 1)\left[z^{(n-1)} + z^{(n-2)} + \cdots + z^2 + z + 1\right]. \tag1$$

Therefore, one approach to the challenge is to look for a way to convert

$$\left[z^4 + z^2 + 1\right]$$

into the rightmost factor of equation (1) above.

One obvious try is to look for a specific value of $n$ such that $$z^4 = z^1 \implies \{z^3 = 1 ~\text{or}~ z = 0\}.$$